# awk comparing two files

Tags: join, awk, compare

I need and awk script that compare the first column of two files tab-delimited and each time there is a match I need to print the second file else I need all the lines of the first file

**file1.txt**

```
denovo0  bacteria   0.99  
denovo1  bacteria   0.98  
denovo2  bacteria;Firmicutes;clostridium    0.99  
denovo3  bacteria;Firmicutes;bacillus   0.98
```

**file2.txt**

```
denovo0  bacteria;Gammaproteobacteria;pseudomonas   0.99  
denovo1  bacteria;Alphaproteobacteria;Rhizobium     0.98
```

**desired_output.txt**

```
denovo0  bacteria;Gammaproteobacteria;pseudomonas  0.99  
denovo1  bacteria;Alphaproteobacteria;Rhizobium  0.98  
denovo2  bacteria;Firmicutes;clostridium    0.99  
denovo3  bacteria;Firmicutes;bacillus   0.98
```

Comment: code tags are for better understanding of question/answers please add them again to have a better look to your post, also please specify more clearly about your problem with examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$1;b[$1]=$0;next} $1==a[$1]{print $0 ;delete b[$1]}END{for (i in b ) print b[i]}'  file1 file2
```

**Explanation**

`NR==FNR{a[$1]=$1;b[$1]=$0;next}` : reads file1 and assigns array `a` with first column and `b` with the line as value.

`$1==a[$1]{print $0 ;delete b[$1]}` : checks if value in `a` matches with 1st column of file2 if yes then print the line of file2 and deleted that line from array `b`.

`END{for (i in b ) print b[i]}`  :
 prints the remaining items in array `b` i.e remaining lines of file1

Comment: Please provide an explanation of how your code works and, ideally some example input and the output your code produces using that input.

Comment: let me know which part specifically you did not understand ? Input and out put are exactly same as OP.

Comment: Explain what your code does and show what it does and I'll let you know if there are more questions. If all goes well your answer will be in the public domain for decades. Document it now. Don't wait for someone to ask you to explain it in 17 years time :)

Comment: `NR==FNR{a[$1]=$1;b[$1]=$0;next}`  reads file1 and assigns array `a` with first column and `b` with the line as value.  `$1==a[$1]{print $0 ;delete b[$1]}` checks if value in `a` matches with 1st column of file2 if yes then print the line of file2 and deleted that line from array `b`. `END{for (i in b ) print b[i]}` prints the  remaining items in array `b` i.e remaining lines of file1 .

Comment: Edit your answer with this info. No-one is going to read all these unformatted comments :).

Comment: @Vicky thank you very much!!, actually your code worked better than the first one. For some reasons, the anubhava code replaced the line of the second file, in the first file as I wanted, but some lines lost the tab delimiter.   Thank you!!

Comment: @Alberto Pascale , you can upvote my answer it that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` should work for you:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next} $1 in a{$2=a[$1]} 1' file2 file1

denovo0 |bacteria;Gammaproteobacteria;pseudomonas| 0.99
denovo1 |bacteria;Alphaproteobacteria;Rhizobium| 0.98
denovo2 |bacteria;Firmicutes;clostridium|   0.99
denovo3 |bacteria;Firmicutes;bacillus|  0.98
```

If you want a tabular output then pipe it to `column -t`

```
awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next} $1 in a{$2=a[$1]} 1' file2 file1 | column -t

denovo0  |bacteria;Gammaproteobacteria;pseudomonas|  0.99
denovo1  |bacteria;Alphaproteobacteria;Rhizobium|    0.98
denovo2  |bacteria;Firmicutes;clostridium|           0.99
denovo3  |bacteria;Firmicutes;bacillus|              0.98
```

Comment: It is because OP changes sample data after my answer. I have updated my answer now.

Comment: thanks @anubhava !!! it worked perfectly! actually the first one worked, since the original files were already tab delimited

Comment: Sorry anubhava, taking a closer look at the output file, I noticed that for some reasons some of the replaced lines lost the format. I don't understand why, these lines were all space delimited instead of tab delimited

Comment: I have added `-v OFS='\t'` in my `awk` solution so that output is tab delimited only. Also note that you have not mentioned anywhere in question that your input has tabs instead of spaces shown in question.